# MySQL match against from different tables

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Compositions of tables is like:

table

| id | name | id_table2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 10 |
| 23 | row | 44 |

table2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Bob |
| 44 | another row |

table3

| id | name | id_table2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | Zotty | 10 |
| 90 | Solo | 44 |

Composition is basically the same, but are different entities.
table and table3 as both a reference on table2, table and table2 needs to return result based on a score by

1. name field in their table
2. if table3 has a match with an id_table2, needs to add that score and add that relevance to the score

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(a.id) AS id,
    MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+Test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM
    table AS t
WHERE
    ...
    ...
UNION
ALL
SELECT
    DISTINCT(b.id) AS id,
    MATCH (b.name) AGAINST ('+Test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score   
FROM
    table2 AS t2
WHERE
    ...
    ...
GROUP BY
    id
LIMIT
    50
```

What I want to do is adding another `MATCH AGAINST` that point to another table3. I've already tried to do something like:

```
   SUM (MATCH (a.name) AGAINST ('+Test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + MATCH (c.name) AGAINST ('+Test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS score
```

Printing these values result in:
a) Singular score of first Match returns 0
b) Singular score of second Match return 0
c) SUM of scores (case a and b) returns a total different values (Ex. 1.8)

Comment: `table` and `table3` seem identical.  Can they be the same table??

Comment: Cannot be, are different entities, consider that here I have synthesized the columns needed for this case, but actually tables are bigger than this :/